# Writing from one file to another

Tags: python

I've been stuck on this Python homework problem for awhile now: "Write a complete python program that reads 20 real numbers from a file inner.txt and outputs them in sorted order to a file outter.txt."

Alright, so what I do is:

```
f=open('inner.txt','r')
n=f.readlines()
n.replace('\n',' ')
n.sort()
x=open('outter.txt','w')
x.write(print(n))
```

So my thought process is: Open the text file, n is the list of read lines in it, I replace all the newline prompts in it so it can be properly sorted, then I open the text file I want to write to and print the list to it. First problem is it won't let me replace the new line functions, and the second problem is I can't write a list to a file.

Comment: write a loop to do the replacement and writing for one string at a time. And don't use `print`.

Comment: `n` is a *list*.  It doesn't have a `replace` method.

Comment: here's a full program that reads all numbers and assumes that the file contains nothing but whitespace-separated real numbers: `open('outter.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(map(str, sorted(map(float, open('inner.txt', 'rb').read().split())))))` Do not use it as is. Rewrite it piece by piece: use multiple lines, add variables, don't read the whole file at once, etc. Look up the docs for every method used. It should help to provide you the understanding necessary to unstack.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - is it possible that you interpret the text into a float and then when making it output into a string you get a slightly different result because it's a float?

Comment: @TimTisdall only if it has more precision than float, f.ex `'1.4999999999999999999999992'`, but in that case you'll have hard time sorting those.

Comment: @TimTisdall: it is a good question. To avoid [discussing rounding issues such as in issue1580](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580), the decompressed code could use `key=float` parameter to sort a list of strings that contain floats.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - that would be perfect!  It'd also handle cases like "03.300\n" as the output would have the same formatting instead of becoming "3.3".

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this:

```
>>> x= "34\n"
>>> print(int(x))
34
```

So, you shouldn't have to filter out the `"\n"` like that, but can just put it into `int()` to convert it into an integer.  This is assuming you have one number per line and they're all integers.

You then need to store each value into a list.  A list has a [`.sort()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) you can use to then sort the list.

EDIT:
forgot to mention, as other have already said, you need to iterate over the values in `n` as it's a list, not a single item.

Comment: seems to also work with `float()`, which might be better if "real" means it could be decimal values

Answer (score 1):

Here's a step by step solution that fixes the issues you have :)

Opening the file, nothing wrong here.

```
f=open('inner.txt','r')
```

Don't forget to close the file:

`f.close()`

`n` is now a list of each line:

```
n=f.readlines()
```

There are no `list.replace` methods, so I suggest changing the above line to `n = f.read()`. Then, this will work (don't forget to reassign `n`, as strings are immutable):

```
n = n.replace('\n','')
```

You still only have a string full of numbers. However, instead of replacing the newline character, I suggest splitting the string using the newline as a delimiter:

`n = n.split('\n')`

Then, convert these strings to integers:

```
`n = [int(x) for x in n]`
```

Now, these two will work:

```
n.sort()
x=open('outter.txt','w')
```

You want to write the numbers themselves, so use this:

```
x.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in n))
```

Finally, close the file:

`x.close()`

Using a context manager (the `with` statement) is good practice as well, when handling files:

```
with open('inner.txt', 'r') as f:
    # do stuff with f
# automatically closed at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `real` means float. So you have to convert your results to float to sort properly.

```
raw_lines = f.readlines()
floats = map(float, raw_lines)
```

Then you have to sort it. To write result back, you have to convert to string and join with line endings:

```
sortеd_as_string = map(str, sorted_floats)
result = '\n'.join(sortеd_as_string)
```

Finally you have have to write result to destination.

Comment: as [@TimTisdall pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20447594/writing-from-one-file-to-another#comment30549562_20447594), there could be an issue with the `str(float(s)) == s` round-trip. `raw_lines.sort(key=float)` could be used to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's look it step by step what you want to do.

**First: Read some integers out of a textfile.**

Pythonic Version:

```
fileNumbers = [int(line) for line in open(r'inner.txt', 'r').readlines()]
```

Easy to get version:

```
fileNumbers = list()
with open(r'inner.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for singleLine in fh.readlines():
        fileNumbers.append(int(singleLine))
```

What it does:

1. Open the file
2. Read each line, convert it to int (because readlines return string values) and append it to the list `fileNumbers`

**Second: Sort the list**

```
fileNumbers.sort()
```

What it does:
The `sort` function sorts the list by it's value e.g. `[5,3,2,4,1] -> [1,2,3,4,5]`

**Third: Write it to a new textfile**

```
with open(r'outter.txt', 'a') as fh:
    [fh.write('{0}\n'.format(str(entry))) for entry in fileNumbers]
```